# vb.net convert value to string

Tags: vb.net, string

Not sure how to do this, here is my code

```
 Dim oWeb As New System.Net.WebClient()

    oWeb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    Dim bytArguments As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username=username&password=password")
    Dim bytRetData As Byte() = oWeb.UploadData("https://www.website.com", "POST", bytArguments)
    MsgBox(oWeb.ResponseHeaders.GetValues(2))
```

Im attempting to get the cookies saved then use it for another post data i want to do, but I keep getting logged off in like 1 second.

The error is

```
Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.
```

for the message box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144271.aspx) returns an array of strings, which the MessageBox has trouble displaying.

When I change the line to

```
MsgBox(String.Join(",", oWeb.ResponseHeaders.GetValues(2)))
```

It works, so you need to decide how you wish to concatenate the string array that is being returned.